# Parsing ifconfig response using regular expression

Tags: regex

I would like to retrieve IP addresses from the following output.

```
vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet 
          inet addr:192.168.185.1  Bcast:192.168.185.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I want to fetch the IP & mask and the result will be

```
192.168.185.1

255.255.255.0
```

Can anyone tell me the regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a third try, here it is.

```
(addr|Mask):([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2}).([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2}).([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2}).([0-1]{1}[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[0-9]{1,2})
```

It now picks only valid IP adressses, as long as there is addr or Mask in front of it.

Comment: Thanks

and the output is:

addr:192.168.185.1
Mask:255.255.255.0

Can just out as:
192.168.185.1

255.255.255.0

Comment: You can remove the addr and Mask with a replace function of the language you are coding in. This will probably be way easier than getting it out with the regex.

Comment: is there any method not display addr: and Mask:?

Comment: i am trying to make a example that removes it. i will tell you what i find.

Comment: removing the addr and mask without breaking my regex is to much for me. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
/addr\:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*Mask\:([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following `awk` line :

```
awk -F'[ :]' '/inet addr/{print $13 "\n" $19}'
```

Comment: For this example, it will be ok. But the length of the ip address will be different. And the format will be inet addr:{IP}  ****** Mask:{maskip}.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain your format is consistent then something as simple as this should do the trick:

```
inet addr:([^\sB]*).*Mask:(.*)$
```